# My 1 yr old nectorine tree only has branches at bottom the top has nothing. They are not suckers

Tags: fruit-trees

My 1 year old nectorine tree only has branches at bottom.  Top 2-3feet has nothing

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site.  Do you have a specific question about your tree?  Can you provide more information about where in the world it is?  Maybe even a picture?

Comment: Does bottom mean ground level or a few feet up? Below ground are suckers from root stock, to be cut whenever you see them.